# How do I create multiple strings from one string?

Tags: c#

I want to filter out all the sections of numbers of a string and add them all to a list of strings.

So from: `["2931741444","2931789497","2931745064","2931763896","2931728251","2931786984","2931799607","293177823","2931795568","293171105"]`

to

```
list.Add(2931741444);
list.Add(2931789497);
list.Add(2931745064);
```

etc...

I loop through the string, look at where the numbers began and add them to a new string, but I'm stuck now. Here's my attempt:

static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            var json = wc.DownloadString("http://api.hivemc.com/v1/game/SG/data");
            Console.WriteLine(json);
            Console.WriteLine("Was called first.");

            int counter = 2;
            string newString = "";
            string s = json.ToString();
            // loop through the string
            for (int i=0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {

                if (s[i].ToString() == "\"")
                {
                    counter++;
                }

                if (counter.isEven)
                {
                    newString = newString + i;
                }
            } 
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Is there an easier way to do this? I also can't see how I would do the other strings with this code.

Comment: `I'm stuck now` This does not describe the problem. Please be more specific about the actual problem being encountered.

Comment: some words got deleted from the fdirst sentence. sorry about that. I'll fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is `deserialization`. You can use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
var list = new List<long>();
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    var json = wc.DownloadString("http://api.hivemc.com/v1/game/SG/data");
    list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<long>>(json);
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: wit the edit, that *might* work, but I would forgive any json framework that refused to go directly from `"123"` to `int`; I guess it would be library specific

Comment: @tnw sorry about that, fixed it.

Comment: @MarcGravell I changed the code, it works using `long`

Answer (score 1):

```
var stringValues = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(json);
int[] values = Array.ConvertAll(stringValues, s => int.Parse(s));
```

?

(feel free to swap for any other json serializer library there; the example is with Json.NET)